# Mainstage external send effect with RME TotalMix

Tags: mixer, effects

How do I set up an FX unit, (G Major) to be used as an external send effect? I have selected "Add Aux Channel Strip" by the "Send" area on my guitar track in Mainstage. What should the setting in the RME TotalMix be? I'm not having any luck sending audio via SPDIF to G Major using the IO plugin on the aux track. The only way I can get sound to the G-Major is by increasing the "PSA-1 CAB 6" input on the SPDIF-output submix (second image), but that causes the Aux Send track and the Send amount to be unusable to adjust the effect as it is always on. I want to be able to route the return signal from G-Major from SPDIF input to Audio 1-2 output. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to enable output on the Software Playback SPDIF, and select channel 9-10 as both input and output in Mainstage's I/O plugin.

[image]

[image]